# News Feed settings Showing error in SharePoint 2016 mysite

Tags: my-site, newsfeed, sharepoint-on-prem, 2016

I am working in SharePoint 2016 Beta 2 version, in which I created my site host which is working correctly, but I am not getting how to configure News feed Settings.

To see the error please refer the image aligned with this post.

[image]

Comment: The error in the image is very difficult to make out.  Can you provide the error message in your post?